# Derive method return type from parameter type

Tags: c#, function, return-value, func

I want to know if it's possible to create a method like this:

```
public var test (var value)
{
    // ...
    return value;
}
```

Meaning, if `value` is a `bool`, I want to return a `bool`, if `value` is a `string`, I want to return a `string`, etc.

Comment: Do you want to return the `type` of the given argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your return type is supposed to be the same as the type of your `value` parameter, you could create a method with a generic parameter:

```
public T Test<T>(T value)
{
    return value;
}
```

Learn more about generics [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/).

You mentioned that you could also do this using the `dynamic` keyword, but I would advise against the use of `dynamic` for a scenario like this. In some special cases `dynamic` should be used over generics, but it mainly becomes relevant when you're dealing with COM interop.

Answer (score 1):

According to your final statement, you want to return the same type that you receive in input, so, you can do it with a Generic function

```
public T test<T>(T input)
{
    return input;
}

void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(test(true));
    Console.WriteLine(test(1));
    Console.WriteLine(test("Steve"));
}
```

[More info on Generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/)

Comment: tnx but know i found a way using dynamic type, so know question is which one is better? generic or dynamic?

Comment: If your _better_ means performance then dynamics will be slower because they are using runtime invocation.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way:

```
public dynamic GetAnything(dynamic val)
{
    return val;
}
```